# order array number using $filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a number array and want to order it by number.

```
$scope.ListProducts = $filter('orderBy')($scope.ListProducts, 'Price', true);
```

Its result are: order array ListProduct by string value.

Example:
Price Array: `1, 4, 12 => 1, 12, 4`
I want: `1, 4, 12`

Thank you very much

Comment: You're probably sorting strings, not numbers

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Did you verify that your array only contains elements of the type number? It seems to me that you have string representations of numbers in your array.

Comment: Parse the price property from strings to numbers, then sort it.

Comment: Angular's filter can sort numbers just fine, providing they has the "number" type. Double-check your input data.

Comment: I have just conver array from string to number and resolved it. thank you so much